# Marathon loses control over Mesos when Marathon and Mesos leaders mismatch

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, marathon

When mesos or marathon service restart due to some reasons and leader of mesos and marathon is not on the same machine, deployments stuck in marathon and nothing happens in mesos, that leads to terrible results when marathon can not restart failed services and do nothing with deployments until leaders will not match again.

Our cluster has 3 masters (installed through mesosphere website) and this situation happens quite often, is there any way to fix that?

Marathon v.0.9.0
Mesos v0.22.1

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like either Mesos or Marathon use a private ip (localhost/127.0.0.1), thus they weren't able to *talk* to each other.
You should be able to solve your issue by setting a public ip using the respective `--ip` command line flag or `LIBPROCESS_IP` environment var.

> One particularly useful setting is LIBPROCESS_IP, which tells the master and slave binaries which IP address to bind to; in some installations, the default interface that the hostname resolves to is not the machine’s external IP address, so you can set the right IP through this variable.

/source http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/deploy-scripts/